# Dynamically build the updateexpression and ExpressionAttribute Value for Dynamodb update_item

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table storing user details/settings for an application and have an Lambda called by API Gateway to manage users.

When I want to update a user's settings I am sending a PUT request from API to Lambda with attributes to be updated as requestBody.

I am able to do the update item if I have all of the attributes as part of my Update Expression and Expression Attribute value in the code.

```
if 'DisplayName' in requestBody and 'isActive' not in requestBody and 'userType' not in requestBody and 'notificationEmail' not in requestBody:
  displayName = requestBody['DisplayName']
  UpdateExpression = 'SET displayName = :val1'
  ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ':val1': displayName
        }
elif 'DisplayName' in requestBody and 'isActive' in requestBody and 'userType' not in requestBody and 'notificationEmail' not in requestBody:
displayName = requestBody['DisplayName']
isActive = requestBody['isActive']
UpdateExpression = 'SET displayName = :val1, isActive = :val2'
ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ':val1': displayName,
        ':val2': isActive
    }
try:
update_user = config_table.update_item(
  Key ={
    'pk': pk_update,
    'sk': 'USER'
  },
  UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression,
  ExpressionAttributeValues=ExpressionAttributeValues,
  ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

But I dont want to look through the Body for every attribute and construct the UpdateExpression and ExpressionAtrributeValue but dynamically build them with whatever is sent in the requestbody.

Comment: You would need to write a custom function / logic to dynamically set these values for each UpdateExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues respectively. I can jot something down that could work.

Comment: I am new to python and not sure how I can get that to work but if you can give me something that will be great.